# How to Get Facebook Friends List with Profile Picture and urls in v2.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had an application before which extracted my friends list with profile pictures but because Facebook depreciated v1.0 API so it is now not working.

Now I want to extract my friends list with API v2.0 and here is the command I am using to do this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=  [oauth_token]&fields=name,id,picture
```

The issue is that it only shows the total count of my friends but not there name and ids like this

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
 "summary": {
"total_count": 258
 }
}
```

In the Debug menu it shows this message!

```
Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.
```

Can somebody let me know if I am doing something wrong or what should be the command to extract my friends information with API v2.0.

Thank You!

Comment: You are doing everything correct. In API v2.0 you only get friends that have granted user_friends permission to your app. Just like the message say

Comment: So isn't there any other way to gather my friends name and id using this API?

Comment: Ok thx if anybody else has a solution please do let me know about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the comments, it is not possible to get all friends anymore - only those who authorized your App too. You can read about this in detail in the answer of this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)